# Creating user with password Authentication at Presto Database

Tags: jdbc, presto

I Have a presto Database.

I want to create a new user which will be used by creating a connection via JDBC connection

I was searching [this link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/index.html)

for creating user syntax 
this is the only create options it has

```
8.5. CREATE SCHEMA
8.6. CREATE TABLE
8.7. CREATE TABLE AS
8.8. CREATE VIEW
```

The `CREATE SCHEMA`  doesn't appear to have the ability for it - it also doesn't appear to have IDENTIFIED BY syntax.

How can I create a user with a password for Presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto does not have the notion of users or storage of its own. It relies on the underlying data source. Which connectors are you using? If you're using the Hive connector, then depending on how it's configured you could connect as a particular Hive user.

Comment: What about [Presto Memory tables](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/memory.html), which creds to use?